# Signout is not working in Django

Tags: python, django, logout

I have tried to call the signout url from template then redirect to home page.

profile.html:

```
<li><a data-hover="Logout" href="{% url 'signout' %}">Logout</a></li>
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^ajax/validate_username/$', views.validate_username, name='validate_username'),
    url(r'^signout$', views.signout, name='signout'),
]
```

views.py:

```
def signout(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        logout(request)
        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/')
    else:
        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/')
```

Sometimes signout functionality is not working, while clicking the logout menu(The function signout is calling).

Comment: What does "not working" mean? do your breakpoints in the view get hit? are you logged out? do you get any errors?

Comment: It is not logged out and no errors. The same page is loading while click the logout menu. While clicking the menu, it would call the function(signout) and redirect to home, but the function is not calling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably, you should use `HttpResponseRedirect` instead of `HttpResponsePermanentRedirect`. Because permanent redirection could use cache that you don't need if you intend to run `signout` always.

Also you can do signout like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^signout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': 'home'}, name='signout'),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks, Its working with the url 'localhost:8000'. But if i use the url '127.0.0.1:8000', signout is not working rather than redirect to same woking page. May i know the reason?

Comment: Never met the difference between 127.0.0.1 and localhost. Probably you've got saved some URLs in cache. Clean the cache and repeat your requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code, It will work.

url(r'^signout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',
                           {'next_page': '/login/'}, name='signout')